# Use multiple selection in a listview with customized list rows

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, customization

My objective is to be able to select multiple rows from a listview that was populated using a simple cursor adapter in order to delete them, I´ve checked many tutorials but some of them don´t use data from the database or others don´t use custom rows. 
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Of course there are ways to do it! What have you tried?

Comment: Well, so far I tried using the simple cursor adapter, but if I use the second parameter to specify my modfified row, I can no longer use the simple_list_choice_mode parameter. On the other hand, if I use it, I can no longer choose my own row, so far I haven´t been able to implement multiple selection if a modified row is involved-

Comment: I´ve been doing some research and it seems that a custom adapter is needede, I also found one blog http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/ But I don´t really understand what he is doing.